# How to read and convert a nested Object into another object with required data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my nested Object which i have.I need to read this and convert.

```
{
  "_id": "config",
  "_rev": "11-57a",
  "config": {
    "A": {
      "a1": {
        "required": true,
        "editable": true
      },
      "a2": {
        "required": true,
        "editable": true
      },
      "a3": {
        "required": false,
        "editable": false
      },
      "a4": {
        "required": false,
        "editable": true
      },
      "a5": {
        "required": true,
        "editable": true
      },
      "a6": {
        "required": false,
        "editable": true
      }
    },
    "B": {
      "b1": "b22",
      "b2": "b23"
    },
    "C": {
      "c1": "c22",
      "c2": "c33"
    }
  }
}
```

I have to read the above data and convert into the following format

```
{
"_id":"config",
"config":{
"A":{
"a1":{"required":true},
"a2":{"required":true},
"a3":{"required":false},
"a4":{"required":false},
"a5":{"required":true},
"a6":{"required":false}
}
}
}
```

How can i convert like this in javascript?

Comment: Iterate through your source object e.g. with Object.entries, Object.keys or similar and write the properties of your choice to the new object.

Comment: You only want to keep anything that has the required property?

Comment: @AldoSanchez yeah i want to do that

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at https://lodash.com/docs#get.  Otherwise, you're going to have to loop through every nest of your object, which can look kind of ugly.